# Is $S(a \cdot b)$ always less than $S(a) \cdot S(b)$

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $S$ be the sum of digits of a natural number.

I'm wondering if we have $$\forall (a,b) \in \mathbb{N}^2,S(a\cdot b)\le S(a)\cdot S(b)$$

I tried with some examples and for the moment it works, but its not a demonstration.

So I tried like this :

$$(a,b)=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\cdot 10^k,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k\cdot 10^k\right)$$

Then $$a\cdot b=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}a_k\cdot b_l\cdot 10^k\cdot10^l\ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k\cdot b_k \cdot 10^{2k}$$

And now... well I don't know, any help will be appreciate, I should be glad.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Yes it's true.  This follows from the fairly well-known fact that the base-$10$ representation of a positive integer $n$ is the *shortest* possible representation of $n$ as a sum of powers of $10$.  Note that your product computation gives an explicit representation of $a\cdot b$ as a sum of $S(a)\cdot S(b)$ powers of $10$.

Comment: The next step is to carry tens.  This reduces one digit by 10 and increases the next digit by 1; so it reduces the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already finished:

We have

$$a\cdot b=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}a_k\cdot b_l\cdot 10^k\cdot10^l$$
you have expressed $ab$ as a sum of $S(a)S(b)$ powers of $10$ (the sum of all the $a_kb_l$).

Of course the actual base $10$ representation of a number $n$ is the way to express $n$ as the sum of the least number of  powers of $10$, so it uses $S(a)S(b)$ or less powers of $10$.

In fact the inequality is an equality if and only if $\sum_{l+k=j}a_ka_l$ is less than ten for every $j$.

Comment: Isn't it that the sum is strict if and only if $\sum_{l+k=j} a_k a_l$ is more than ten for every $j$?

Comment: Sorry, the inequality is an equality if and only if $\sum_{l+k=j}a_ka_j$ is less than $10$. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try a proof:

For univariate polynomials, we always have equality:
let $P,Q \in\mathbb N[X]$ be univariate polynomials, and $T(P)$ denote the sum of the coefficients of $P$.
Then we have $T(P\cdot Q)=T(P)\cdot T(Q)$.

Now if we assume that the coefficients are in $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ and we evaluate $P$ and $Q$ at $X=10$, $S(P(10))\cdot S(Q(10))=T(P)\cdot T(Q)$, but
$S(P(10)\cdot Q(10))\leq T(P\cdot Q)$.

Consequently, for any $a,b\in\mathbb N$, $S(a\cdot b)\leq S(a)\cdot S(b)$.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me but thank you ! :)